# what is wrong in this strcmp()?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcmp

I try to write simple `C` function with `strcmp()`. But I always get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. What is wrong ?

```
char *arr={"abcdefg"};
char *a = arr[1];

if(strcmp(a, 'b') == 0)
{
    printf("it is b \n");
}
```

Comment: `'b'` is of `char` type. It should be `"b"`.

Comment: `'b'` is a char. `strcmp` needs a string (so a `char*`).

Comment: `a` doesn't point to where you think it points. If the compiler doesn't shout warnings as you fir this code, then you need to enable more warnings.

Comment: I get same error with "b"

Comment: By the way `arr[1]` is also a char, put into a char *.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you enable all compiler warnings and do not ignore any of them. The compiler will tell you about this one.

Comment: ...and `-Wall` is **not** "all compiler warnings". ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Even defaults gcc warning wouldn't allow this...

Comment: use man strcmp.. and find the error.

Comment: this is not a direct answer to your question, but since it seems that you are trying to compare 2 char values, why don't you just write a simple condition like if (arr[1] == 'b')

Comment: Yes, implicit casting integer→pointer (for `a`) and bad argument type matching  (for `b`) is very basic warning :)

Comment: @Kotshi: I wouldn't know, I never use a compiler *without* warnings enabled. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is wrong?

You did not let yourself be helped by the compiler.

Using `-Wall -Wextra` on GCC (which is by no means the best you can get but rather the bare minimum you should always use), I get:

```
testme.c: In function ‘main’:
testme.c:6:11: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 char *a = arr[1];
           ^
```

You took `arr[1]` -- which is the `char` value `'b'` -- and *turned it into a `char *`*. Your `a` is now pointing to whatever is at address `0x62` (assuming ASCII), which is most definitely not what you intended. You probably wanted `&arr[1]`, or `arr + 1`.

Or you *wanted* a `char` -- then you shouldn't declare `char *`, and `strcmp()` would be the wrong thing to use in the first place.

```
testme.c:8:1: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 if(strcmp(a, 'b') == 0)
 ^
In file included from testme.c:1:0:
/usr/include/string.h:144:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
            ^
```

`strcmp()` expects two C strings (`char const *`). Your second argument `'b'` is of type `int`... you probably wanted `"b"`.

Which still would not compare equal, because `"bcdefg"` is not equal `"b"`...

Or you *wanted* a one-character comparison... that would be `if ( a == 'b' )` then, with `a` being of type `char`, not `char *` (see above).

```
testme.c:10:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     printf("it is b \n");
     ^
testme.c:10:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
```

Please do us all the favour of posting *complete* code, includes, `int main()` and all, so we can copy & paste & compile, and still have line numbers match.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you have been trying to achieve :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *arr = {"abcdefg"};
    char a = arr[1];

    if( a == 'b' )
    {
        printf("it is b \n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a number of things wrong here. `strcmp` is for comparing strings. The simplest way to do what you want is

```
char *arr= {"abcdefg"};
char a = arr[1];

if(a == 'b')
{
  printf("it is b \n");
}
```

If you still want to do it with `strcmp`, you need to make `a` a string by appending the null terminator `\0` to it.

```
char *arr= {"abcdefg"};
char a[] = {arr[1], '\0'};

if(strcmp(a, "b") == 0)
{
  printf("it is b \n");
}
```